# Find out whether the device is in power saving mode or not android

Tags: android

I need to check whether the device is in power saving mode or not programmatically android.My application is run on 24/7.So in power saving mode ,network disabled and device goes to sleep.

Answer (score 9):

Check this code.

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
            && powerManager.isPowerSaveMode())
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can detect this by isPowerSaveMode () which returns boolean according to the mode of android device.

You can get more info [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isPowerSaveMode())